# How can I bake textures while specifying a seperate base texture?

Tags: uv

I know this must be a simple problem, but in order to bake my textures, I have to set a base image for my object. After I have done this, I can then bake the texture but it *overwrites* my originally set texture with the baked texture.

If I then move objects in the scene etc, and re-bake the textures, the incorrect UV mapped texture is used as the base texture.

How can I keep my base texture as the original material, and render the baked texture result to a seperate image/material every time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bake to texture, Blender looks for any actively selected image texture nodes to determine where to bake.  If you want to bake to a new image, create a new image texture node and a new image for it.  It does not need to be plugged into anything.  Select that node (only that node) then bake.

Comment: "Select that node" are we talking selecting a node in the shader editor, or where should I select that node? Also, if I wanted to do this for multiple objects, does the same principle apply? You're not my personal Blender Slave but if had any screenshots as well that would be amazing.

Comment: Yes, select that node in the shader editor.  Do this in every material that you are baking; each material maintains its own active selection.  You can bake to different images from different materials, or to the same image from different materials.

Comment: Thanks - I've noticed that since doing this, and then exporting to wavefront (.obj), the materials aren't listed in the .mtl file. Is there a way I can use an original texture and show the object's baked textures, but not have that change the original base texture on the item?

Comment: @LewisCianci Sorry, I don't know exactly how Blender exports .mtl files.  But you can always edit them-- they are just text.

Comment: Hmm but in a scene with 10 objects that you want to export at the same time, editing 10 files every time you update and export would become tedious. Maybe that's better asked in another question.